# Re-running .getJSON on .click to return new results(jQuery/AJAX)

Tags: ajax, jquery, flickr, getjson

This is driving me crazy, but first I would like to apologize. I am very new to javascript/jquery.  I did, however, do my best to solve this by searching relentlessly, and to no avail.

Here's my issue: I am implementing a Flickr photo gallery for a client b/c she insists on using it to upload her pictures.  To do this I am using a slider gallery I purchased, and some jQuery/AJAX to create all the functions/requests.  The slider is a jQuery script that uses specifically structured selectors to create the slideshow. The structure is like this:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="path/to/img.jpg"/>
        <img class="thumbnail" src="path/to/img_thumbnail.jpg"/>
        <div class="caption">My Caption</div>
        <div class="thumbnail-caption">My Thumb Caption</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The function I setup is like this:

```
   var $currentPage = 1;
    var $totalPages;
    var $sliderHTML = "<div class='slider'></div>";
    var $perPage = 18;

    function flickr(){
       $(function (){
            $($sliderHTML).prependTo("#portfolio");
            $.getJSON('http://path/to/flickr?perpage=' + $perPage + '&page=' + $currentPage + '&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
                function(data){

                    $totalPages = Math.ceil(data.photos.total / $perPage);

                    $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){

                   // Loop results and grab all variables I need - Examples omitted

                   // After which, append variables to string

               var $sliderItem = '<div class="slider-item"><img height="' + imgHeight + '" src="' + photoURLo + '" alt="' + photoTitle + '" /><img height="75" width="75" class="thumbnail" src="' + photoURLm + '" alt="' + photoTitle + '" /><div class="caption">' + photoTitle + '</div><div class="thumbnailCaption">' + photoTitle + '</div></div>';

                   // Then append to the main div 

                  $($sliderItem).appendTo(".slider");

           });
      });

    }

// Finally call the function on document.ready

$(document).ready(function(){
   flickr();
});
```

To make sure the slider doesn't load until the flickr function is completed (which was causing screw-ups) I just wrapped it in a function and call it on window.load. which works perfectly.  And finally I initialize the slider w/ a window.load event.

```
$(window).load(aSlider()); // loads the slider script
$(window).load(advSlider()); // initializes the slider
```

The whole setup works great. Initially.

Here's the issue.  I need to call more pictures and this is not working at all! Here's the code snippet in my HTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#moreSlides').click(function (){
            if($totalPages == $currentPage){ //checks for last page
                $currentPage = 1;            //resets to page one
            }
            else {
                $currentPage++;      // increments page 
            }
            $('.slider').remove();      //removes entire slider div              
            flickr();
            $(".slider-item").ajaxComplete(aSlider());
            advSlider();
        });
 </script>
```

One way or another this always fails.  I have tried stepping through this click event in the console and what it basically looks like is that it gets to the flickr() function and just passes over it instead of executing the function (which I can see happen if I step through it in the console on load).  However, it does eventually execute the function... it creates the div class=slider, and within it, my loading animation, but after that it does not load the slide-items until after it executes the aSlider() function.

I have reproduced what I want to happen in the console manually and it works fine: Increment the $currentPage: check.  Remove the .slider div: check. Execute flickr():check. Execute aSlider: check.  Initialize advSlider(): check.  Everything works perfectly with all the second page images showing up.

Something is wrong with the sequence and I simply do not know what it is.  I have tried everything I can find to get the aSlider to wait, but it doesn't work.  Please help!

Thanks

Comment: i think the advSlider() call should be in the ajaxComplete handler aswell. Don't know if that's the problem though

Comment: I have tried this as well, including using the more general $(window).ajaxComplete().  Nothing is working so far though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by creating a setTimeout loop (with if statements).

```
function loadSlides(){
    if($totalPages != $currentPage){  // Making sure we're not on the last page, which may not have the exact $perPage number
        if($('.slider-item').size() == $perPage){ // See if all slides have loaded by counting number of .slider-item and comparing to $perPage variable
            $('#loader').remove();  // Remove loading animation
                aSlider();  // Execute Slider code
                setTimeout(function(){
                    advSlider();  // Instantiate slider (this may not be necessary on the setTimeout here, just being safe)
                },50);
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(function(){  // If all slides haven't loaded, wait 20ms and retry the function.
                loadSlides();
                    },20);
             }
                    }
    else {
        if($('.slider-item').size() == $lastPage){  //This is the same thing as about just takes into account $lastPage instead of $perPage
            $('#loader').remove();
            aSlider();
            setTimeout(function(){
                advSlider();
            },50);
         }
         else {
             setTimeout(function(){
                 loadSlides();
             },20);
         }
    }
}
```

This is what I had to do to make this work.  I hope it helps someone b/c getJSON can't be loaded synchronously and this seems like a common issue.  Although setTimeout is kind of a hack, using this will allow your code to run more quickly than putting in some generic number like some people seem to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    aSlider();
    },1600);
});
```

Using setTimeout like that is terrible b/c sometimes its way too long and other times it still isn't long enough.  So in order to get it to always work correctly, you have to set a terribly high timeout.

Like I said, I'm very new to all this so if anyone has a better way of writing this or doing the same time, feel free to answer!

Comment: Also... This allowed everything to work in IE8 which seems to ignore the $(window).load() ordering.